# jquery validation required depends

Tags: jquery, validation, required, depends

I'm using https://jqueryvalidation.org to validate my form.
Now I have an input for IBAN, which is not required, only if another field is filled.
But WHEN it is required, I want to start the IBAN-Check.
When it's not required, I don't want the IBAN-Check.

Here's some code:

```
fm_operator_iban: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#fm_operator_accountname").val().length > 0 || $("#fm_operator_bankname").val().length > 0;
            },
            validIBAN: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return "required";
                }
            }
        }
```

I only need a solution for the validIBAN part.
I tried something which totally didn't work. ;)
Thanks!

Comment: So, you need an IBAN validator?

Comment: No, I have an IBAN validator. But if you put something in the input field, delete it and send the form, it has the IBAN-validation always on. Although it's not required if it's empty. ;)